# My proof that this entire analytic function's range is within epsilon of any complex number,

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

If $f(z)$ is an entire analytic function assuming the values $0$ and $1$, show that for any complex number $a$ and any real number $ϵ>0$ there is a point $z_0$ such that $|f(z_0)−a|<ϵ$

My work:

Assume that there does not exist such a $z_0$ that fulfills the above inequality.

Then, given a complex number $a$, the function

$$h:= f(z)-a$$ does not have any roots.

By the fundamental theorem of algebra, $h$ cannot be a non-constant polynomial.

So we know that $f(z)$ must be an entire function that grows faster than a polynomial, and assumes the values 0 and 1, among other values (thanks to the comments posted below so far.).

Moreover, since the entire function is not constant, by Liouville's Theorem, this function $f(z)$ is $unbounded$.

Now we know that $|f(z)|$ $\to$ $\infty$, as $|z|$ $\to$ $\infty$.

But since we already established that $f$ is not a polynomial, then it does not have a pole at infinity.  Then the singularity of $f$ at infinity must be an essential singularity.

Now we can apply Big Picard's theorem to claim that $f$ attains every complex number $a$, with the exception of at most one value, infinitely often.

Is this ok?

Thanks,

Comment: Liouville's theorem is what you need here, but the intent is to say that it assumes the values $0$ and $1$ among others, not only those values, i.e. it is _not_ constant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)#Entire_functions_have_dense_images

Comment: See.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem

Comment: Hi @DanBrumleve, thanks for your comment; I will try now to put something together on paper.  I gave it some time and just thought about it for a bit -- some things I considered were:  Hadamard's product factorization for entire functions, and how to put together some function, pole-free, so that I can use Liouville's Theorem.

Comment: Thanks @tessellation -- the mentioning of Picard's theorem is a bit puzzling at first, since I am given an entire function f(z) to start with, so I'd need to construct a function that has an essential singularity somewhere.  I'll see what I can come up with :-)

Comment: Hi @DanBrumleve -- I edited my post to include my work so far.  What do you think?  If I remember correctly (I will check this now) a non-constant polynomial's "worst" behavior at infinity is a pole of some order = n.  It cannot have an essential singularity at infinity - I forgot why this is the case, so I will look this up.  Then, since I showed that $f(z)$ is not a polynomial, non-constant, *and* entire (by assumption), then it *must* have an essential singularity at infinity, and with an application of Big Picard, I should be done, I think.  What are your thoughts?  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @RossMillikan, yes good catch - I have edited the proof.  Is the rest of my work ok?  I have to recall why polynomials cannot have an essential singularity at infinity -- so that *this* entire function *must* have one.  Please feel free to comment further.  Thanks,

Comment: And it is now no longer a contradiction proof @RossMillikan..

Comment: You have justified that $f(z)$ is not polynomial, but then assert that it grows faster than any polynomial.  I don't remember that result offhand, but it is decades since I took complex analysis. The rest seems fine to me, but mrf has a simpler way.

Comment: what does "grows faster than a polynomial" mean ? It is absolutely not the case that $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty $ when $f$ is a not a polynomial. That's not what "unbounded" means.

Comment: Hi @mercio, my logic was this:  since $f$ is entire, but non-constant, as it assumes the values 0 and 1, then using Liouville's theorem in reverse order, we know that this function $f$ is unbounded.  But, since it is entire, I am thinking that it cannot grow without bound *on* the complex plane.  And so, I conclude that the growth without bound must occur towards infinity.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much for your time @RossMillikan.

Comment: I've removed the tags ([tag:asymptotics]), ([tag:hadamard-product]), and ([tag:polynomials]) because they don't seem to directly relate to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using big Picard for this is major overkill.

If the image is not dense, there is a point $a$ and an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $|f(z)-a| > \varepsilon$ for all $z$. Put
$$
g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)-a}.
$$
Then $g$ is entire and bounded, thus constant. But this in turn forces $f$ to be constant, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Ah..oh gosh.  If you believe me, @mrf, this was actually my first approach, and I was almost there :-(  Does my proof still work, though?  It would be a nice combination of fundamental theorem of algebra (showing f(z) can't be a non-constant polynomial since f-a has no roots), with the classification of the singularity of this function at infinity, compared with the singularity of a polynomial at infinity.

Comment: Thanks, professor, for such a simple and pretty answer :-).

Comment: Your proof is fine (if you fix some of the wording: it's not the case that "$f$ grows faster than a polynomial" -- but if $f$ is not a polynomial, its Maclaurin series is non-finite, so $f$ will have an essential singularity at $\infty$), but the proof of Big Picard is rather difficult.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much, professor.  It is a good time now to review the classification of singularities of some entire functions.  Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:Show that a non-constant entire function has a dense range

Comment: Thanks so much for the hint @black-horse :-)